# Is there a way to collect Google IDs which access a Google Site?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sites

I have created a Google Site which links to various Google Classrooms. I would like to know who is using the site.

Is there a way of recording the Google ID in a Google Sheet, for when someone accesses the site?

Any help or even a point in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Is the site open to the public, or just available to a specific group of people?

Comment: it is only available to our students

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you are using Google Sites, you can create a user start page by following [these  steps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/184005?hl=en), this page will ask the users to authenticate with their emails, and will allow only users from the organizational unit for which the site is allowed.

After that step, you can [use Google Analytics with your Site](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97459?hl=en) to track the behavior of users in your Site.

I suggest starting with a [quickstart](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/academy/course/6) of Google Analytics to get the hang of it.

And soon enough you will have it set up to suit your needs.